# ともに after a unit of time?

Tags: translation, meaning

I came across these lines in [a song (0:59):](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm24003601)

> 十日ともに
>
> 投げた賽は
>
> 赤く色づいた

As far as I know, ともに means something like "together with," but "together with ten days" doesn't really make much sense.

There's also the less common meaning "both," but again, "both the 10th/ten days, and the die I cast, turned red" doesn't make much sense either.

Am I misinterpreting this? What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

The speaker is referring to how s/he and another person cast the die together over a period of 10 days. The あなたと is omitted.